# How to Select box value selected from db values in angular js like selected in php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Am newbie to angular js please give me the solution.

How to selected Db values selected in select dropdown list like PHP in angular js?

For example Php coding,

```
$array = array("apple", "orange", "lemon");
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach ($array as $data) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data ?>" <?php if ($data == "orange") echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $data ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

So in PHP we selected value means to give echo selected How to do like in angular js?

My Angular Js code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="citizenship3" name="citizenship3" ng-model="attributes.citizenship"  class="example-getting-started form-control"  required>                       
    <option ng-repeat="clist in citizenshipList" value="{{clist.country}}" ng-selected="{{ attributes.citizenship.Selected == true }}">{{clist.country}}</option>
</select>
```

Its fetch all value from DB and also fetching stored db value it's working fine but it's not selected value from DB value How to do Selected in angular js like above PHP coding?Am using ng-selected but it's not working?

My Drop down Design.

[image: DropDownimage]

Answer (score 2):

You can "pre-select" your select by setting correct `ng-model`, as simple as that!

Note that by default the values you code in `<option>` are in string format, it won't work if you use number.

Do consider using `ng-options` for more control of data in `ng-model`.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', function($scope){
  $scope.selected = ["2", "3"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="Test">
  <select multiple ng-model="selected">
    <option value="1" ng-selected="selected.indexOf('1') != -1">one</option>
    <option value="2" ng-selected="selected.indexOf('2') != -1">two</option>
    <option value="3" ng-selected="selected.indexOf('3') != -1">three</option>
    <option value="4" ng-selected="selected.indexOf('4') != -1">four</option>
  </select>
  
  {{selected}}
</div>
```

---

Edit:

Not sure how is your drop down design working, maybe it is detecting the `selected` attribute and some JS manipulation to update the attribute on user click.

I've updated the script so it populates `selected` when user is changing the options, not sure if it would work though.

You'll need to provide the plugin you use so I can look into it further.

Comment: Thanx for your response,plz check Dropdown image in my question,Normal select box it's working fine,But in my above dropdowm design not working

Comment: @AccountTest udated answer

Comment: <li class="ng-binding ng-scope active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="Afghanistan"> Afghanistan</label></a></li> select box selected my design like.how to change active?

Comment: Using bootstrap_multiselect .js.please give me solution

Comment: You can use [angular bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-multiselect) in this case.

Comment: is there any option to set value in boostrap mutiselect js without angular js?refer my another question in stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220649/how-to-select-box-value-selected-from-db-values-in-boostrap-multiselect-js

Answer (score 0):

In your controller. Make a http request which will return the encoded json. Put the return value in a scope then repeat the object using ng-option.

Comment: thanx for your response,normal dropdown it's working fine,but in my dropdown design it's not working check my above image