# How to Select box value selected from db values in boostrap multiselect js?

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

How to selected Db values selected in select dropdown list like PHP in Multiselect boostrap dropdown?

For example Php coding,

```
$array = array("apple", "orange", "lemon");
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach ($array as $data) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data ?>" <?php if ($data == "orange") echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $data ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

In php db value select using Selected,How in Boostrap Multiselect js?

```
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected">
None selected 
<b class="caret">
</b>
```

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
<li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="multiselect-all">
      Select all
    </label>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="cheese">
      Cheese
    </label>
  </a>
</li>
```

How to set value in above boostrap multiselect js? like selected option in php?for example:if db value coming cheese means selected value in Multiselect Dropdown?

Comment: Without the corresponding JavaScript/jQuery code it is hard to tell what you are up to ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the `select` function of the plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();

  $('#example-getting-started').multiselect('select', ['cheese', 'pepperoni']);
});
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wuvixoqihu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

From my understandingof your problem: You are using PHP to generate the select with its option and you retrieve the option and their selected/unselected state form a database. Your code snippet should be fine, Bootstrap Multiselect automatically preserves selected options (both in multiple and single mode). Note that in single mode (i.e. single selection through radio buttons) the *last* selected option is preselected in Bootstrap Multiselect, while in multiple mode all selected options will be preselected.

```
<?php $array = array("apple", "orange", "lemon"); ?>
<select> <!-- Note that the multiple attribute needs to be present to allow multiple selection. -->
<!-- Removed the empty option, not sure what it was for ... -->
<?php foreach ($array as $data): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data ?>" <?php if ($data == "orange") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>><?php echo $data ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- Do not forget closing tag. -->
</select>

<script type="javascript/text">
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Will preselect "orange" in single selection mode ...
     $('select').multiselect({
         includeSelectAllOption: true
     });
});
</script>
```

After page load, the multiselect can be manipulated as described by lcycool.